# Why sign extension errors have high security risks?

Tags: c++, c

Can any one please explain why sign extension errors in any c,c++ programs have high security risks?

I've read that, sign extension errors `"can often create buffer overflows and other memory based problems".`

I read this article on Google,

http://minsky.gsi.dit.upm.es/semanticwiki/index.php/Sign_extension_error

But could not understand how does this affect any application, how can an attacker can exploit this type of vulnerability?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Another person asked this same question today.  Hmmm

Comment: @BrianBeuning Conspiracy! Call the NSA.

Comment: The example on your link is bad code due to blatant misuse of printf. Sign extension isn't the real issue there. Passing a struct by value to printf? Really??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good example is using a char as an index into a table.  The type of char in C can be signed, so any character code > 0x7F will be extended to a negative index into the table. This is equivalent to a buffer overflow attack.  C would have been better off with unsigned char as the default.

Comment: Usually an int is used an index, so "C would have been better off with unsigned char" doesn't really apply.

Comment: I don't call this sign extension. It's merely the correct value of the expression. Sign extension is a *change in value* that happens when you convert a signed type to a wider unsigned type. Like Diti's example.